# Is the HOMFLY Polynomial the best knot invariant?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, homflypt-polynomial

Is the HOMFLY Polynomial the best polynomial invariant that can be calculation from skein relation?

Comment: "Best" has no precise meaning when it comes to polynomial invariants of knots. 

Comment: By 'best' I meant: Is the HOMFLY polynomial better at discriminating knots then other polynomial invariant that are determine by skein relation.

Answer (score 13):

What about the [coloured HOMFLYPT](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601267)? It's clearly stronger than the HOMFLYPT. Whether it is a complete knot invariant is (I believe) open. Mutation preserves the HOMFLYPT polynomial. The 2-variable HOMFLYPT fares better, but also [isn't a complete knot invariant](https://stoimenov.net/stoimeno/homepage/papers/nvi2.pdf). Examples of knots with the same coloured Jones polynomials (all colours), HOMFLYPT, and Kauffman polynomials, but possibly different coloured HOMFLYPT polynomials, are given in Proposition 1.5 [HERE](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=BEFC55B6AB099715EFC3B9206905A852?doi=10.1.1.124.7225&rep=rep1&type=pdf).
I agree that this is a badly posed question which should probably be closed. My motivation for answering is to advertise the references, which I think are lovely papers with closely related results.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I had not come across the coloured HOMFLYPT before. 